# CakePHP Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I'm working on a Cakephp project. My website was working absolutely fine but from last two weeks sometimes it goes down and showing below error. It happens many times in a day.

**Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.**

I try to search it out but didn't get any solution. How can I resolve this? Please Please Help...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Check your logs and review your version control for your changes since then.

Comment: it's perhaps not a Cakephp problem, check your php logs and apache logs and cakephp logs :D

Comment: I tried to check the error log on server. But when I click on error_log it shows  
ERROR: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 50030514 bytes)

Comment: Means your server is requesting for resources and its not enough. Try restarting your server. Then fix your code to make sure its not requesting for too much resource.

Answer (score 1):

**Service Temporarily Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.**

Sometimes the above error showing which means something Server configuration related issue Try to extend memory_limit size.

```
memory_limit
```

Error is not from CakePhp code.

Thanks.